# HtmlUnit connecting to https

Tags: java, https, htmlunit

I encounter a problem when I want to use HtmlUnit (version 2.10) with an https website.

I have initialize an WebClient Object and I have specify some parameters.

```
webClient.setSSLClientCertificate(URL,PASSWORD,"pkcs12");
webClient.setUseInsecureSSL(true);
```

The setUseInsecureSSL method throws an IllegalArgumentException with this message : "Socket factory may not be null"

### Stack trace

> org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme.(Scheme.java:94)
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.createHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:535)
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getHttpClient(HttpWebConnection.java:500)
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.setUseInsecureSSL(HttpWebConnection.java:711)
>   com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.setUseInsecureSSL(WebClient.java:1096)
>   mon.package.HtmlUnitAbstract.setSSLClientCertificate(HtmlUnitAbstract.java:66)

Someone already had this type of error ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Avoid using deprecated methods, try the code below instead:

```
webClient.getOptions().setSSLClientCertificate(URL,PASSWORD,"pkcs12");
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
```